# Downloading snapcraft error

Tags: camera, spotify

[image]I wanted to install spotify and it's not in the application center so I found i can do it via snapcraft and I tried to install it by following this steps ( https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-elementary-os) but then i got this error. And i don't know what to do. I want to have spotify

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to read the error message: Are you root?. Use sudo to run a command with root privileges.

like so: `sudo apt --fix-broken install`